# not equal condtions in elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, conditional-statements

I have a rails app that connects to elastic search and the user could define some conditions like (at least),(at most), and  ... to compare and find his specific result. everything is fine but now I have to add not equal to my comparison operator list and even calculate not equal for all of my conditions described before. for example, if the user wants to search, "not equal at least" I want to calculate the result based on the user query and then make them reverse in result I know make query response reverse, it's impossible in elastic search but does it possible elastic calculate not equal by himself, assume user want to know ((the count of the specific event did not happen at most 1 time in last 30 days)) I know elastic support not equal query, but just in bool and query string query, but in my case, I should use aggregation and terms query in it. aggregation like :

```
body_data =  {
                        group_by_profile_id: {
                            terms: {
                                field: "profile_id.keyword",
                                min_doc_count: @count_first,
                                size: 10000
                            },
                            aggs: {
                                filter: {
                                    bucket_selector: {
                                        buckets_path: {
                                            docCount: "_count"
                                        },
                                        script: "params.docCount #{@operator} #{@counts.last}"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

does anyone knows how can i handle not equal query in aggregation and term query.